# Using into and from in Linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following linq query:

```
var allLocationRates = (from homeLocation in clientLocations
                        from hostLocation in clientLocations
                        select new PaymentRateTrip
                        {
                            HomeCountryId = homeLocation.CountryId,
                            HomeCountry = homeLocation.CountryName,
                            HostCountryId = hostLocation.CountryId,
                            HostCountry = hostLocation.CountryName,
                            HomeLocationId = homeLocation.LocationId,
                            HomeLocation = homeLocation.LocationName,
                            HostLocationId = hostLocation.LocationId,
                            HostLocation = hostLocation.LocationName
                        }
                        into allLocations
                        from l in allLocations // <-- error on this line
                        // continues on...
```

I am trying to get all possible combinations of `clientLocations`.  However, in my query above I get an error on the line `from l in allLocations`.  It reads:

> An expression of type 'PaymentRateTrip' is not allowed in a subsequent
>   from clause in a query expression with source type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'.  Type
>   inference failed in the call to 'SelectMany'.

Why is it selecting only a single `PaymentRateTrip` when it should be selecting a list of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the keyword `into` after a select clause you are doing a "Query Continuation", meaning all following linq-code is operating on the name after `into`. You dont need the line "from l in allLocations", just use 'l' after `into`, like:

```
}
into l
// continues on...
// For example: select l.HomeCountryId
```

More on [Query Continuation](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/09/15/query-expression-syntax-continuations.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, that is perfectly logical :)